# Connector Voltage Ratings Relative/Absolute Across Multiple Pins

Tags: voltage, connector

When using connectors with specific working voltage ratings, does this refer to:

- The relative voltage between any two adjacent pins,
- The absolute voltage relative to anything within the system, or
- The voltage across the gap before the connection is made (like with a relay's switching voltage)?

For example, would a connector with a 50V rating be safely usable in this way?

[image: connector with voltages]

My understanding would be that the voltages only exist relative to each other, so pin 1 at 0V shouldn't care that pin 4 is at 90V, but it equally feels wrong to be using a 90V potential with a "50V" connector.

Comment: How do you guarantee the voltage difference on startup or with fly back voltages.

Comment: it would be between adjacent pins, where high voltage could creep. voltage doesn't really matter to conductors, only insulators, so you would be fine with the above.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 assuming of course that it can be guaranteed one way or another. If there is a possibility of a higher voltage difference between two pins then that would be taken into account.

Comment: If it is a PCB mounting connector, another consideration is the voltage to anything on the board near it. As dandavis mentioned, the normal limit is pin to pin because of creep distances, but this also applied to uncovered tracks on the board below. Also if your circuit is designed commercially there may well be issues in doing this as to everyone and his dog it will be a 50V limit connector.